# l'm getting a "libpng error: Read Error" in my python program

Tags: python, homebrew, libpng

I have a python program that reads .ai files and turns them into png files and then does a cv2.imread on them.  It's been working great, but today I tried to do some threading for the first time on this program to speed it up but it got this error

```
libpng error: Read Error in Python
```

After I got that error I deleted all of the threading code, but weirdly it still kept getting that same error.  I tried the code on different ai images but they all returned the same error.

I read a few other stackoverlow questions that had this some error so I apologize if there's overlap, but the difference is that those questions seemed to be working with C++, or they were programming with Anaconda, which I am not.  There was one answer somewhere that said to "brew uninstall libpng" and then reinstall it.  I tried that but i got this message

```
Error: Refusing to uninstall /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37
because it is required by cairo, fontconfig, freetype, leptonica, openjpeg, poppler, qt, tesseract and webp, which are currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libpng
```

That made me nervous to uninstall libpng so i didn't.  Instead I did "brew reinstall libpng" then I tried the code again but I still got the same error.  Anyways I'm out of ideas, does anyone know how to get rid of that error?

Also, I didn't add the code because it's kind of long and most of it is probably irrelevant but I can if anyone needs it

Comment: The whole point of making a [mre] is that you can remove most of the irrelevant code. We just need the minimal amount of code that produces that error. Anyway, what if you revert everything to how it was before you added the threading? Hopefully you're using source control or some kind of backups of your work, so that you can do that without having to guess how it was beforehand. To me this feels like an issue with the file maybe being open by another program, or by your own program. Have you tried reading an image that you know you haven't tried to read before? Just suggesting some ideas.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't worry in the least about the warning from **homebrew** if I was planning to install again afterwards.